# How can I test the responsiveness of my website on my Android device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm building a website on my Android device and I want to test its responsiveness on other devices (desktop and tablet) on my Android device. How can I do that?

Comment: you can use browser `dev tools` `F12` and `ctrl shift M`

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to accomplish this, maybe for a start you can use:

1. Developer tools from Chrome where it gives you a variety of different devices and screen sizes.
2. You can use `ngrok` to create an instant URL of your localhost where you can use it to test from your personal android device.

There more different ways to do but I would say this is a good start to jump in and explore yourself